# setRGB changes other pixels as well

Tags: java, eclipse, colors, bufferedimage

When I try to copy one pixel color from one bufferedimage to another, it affects the other pixels as well.

This is the 8x8 bufferedimage that I copy the pixel from. getRGB(0,0)

[image: original image]
(original image)

I only copy one pixel value from coordinate 0,0 which is the top left. I'm expecting that when I set the 0,0 pixel in the blank bufferedimage to the one I copied from the first bufferedimage, it would show the output image with the top left pixel of the new bufferedimage to be color green, same as the one from the original, while all other pixels would be black. But unfortunately, other pixels did not stay black, and the top left pixel color isn't even green. (see link below)

[image: new image]
(new image: set top left pixel value to value of top left pixel in original image)

Have I done anything wrong? Or does setRGB really just work that way?

here is my code:

```
    File file = new File("C:\\Users\\Zach\\Documents\\workspace\\8x8.jpg");
    BufferedImage image = null; 

    try {
       image = ImageIO.read(file);

       BufferedImage outputImage = new BufferedImage(image.getHeight(), image.getWidth(), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);

       outputImage.setRGB(0, 0, image.getRGB(0, 0));

       File outputFile = new File ("output1.jpg");
       ImageIO.write(outputImage, "jpg", outputFile);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

However, when I copy the pixel value to all pixels within the new bufferedimage, it all turns to green. Why is it like that? (can't post more than 3 links apparently)

Comment: You might want to show some code, especially the definition of the images and how you read/write the pixels.

Comment: Just new here. Thanks for the tip. I edited my post.

Comment: Ah you're writing jpg. The other pixels being colored might be a problem of the jpg compression which isn't lossless (i.e. it can alter other pixels as well). Try something without compression like .bmp etc. The difference in color might be a problem of the color model that is used, i.e. the input image doesn't use TYPE_INT_RGB but something else and thus the rgb value is misinterpreted.

Comment: ohh, okay.. Let me try that. Thank you.

Comment: From the JavaDoc on `getRGB(x,y)`: "Returns an integer pixel in the default RGB color model (TYPE_INT_ARGB) and default sRGB colorspace." - so try that color model for the output as well.

Comment: Oh!! I can't believe it! Changing it from jpg to bmp worked! Thank you so much, Thomas! You saved my life!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because apart from using JPEG compression, the code posted works as intended. There are plenty other similar questions out there regarding JPEG artifacts.

Comment: You’ll find that PNG is better than BMP, primarily because it’s compressed while BMP is not.  The difference in file size is rather noticeable.